# What does the "atta" mean in "attaboy" and "attagirl"?

Tags: idioms, slang, abbreviations

What does the prefix *atta* mean? What is it trying to abbreviate? *What a*? [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/attaboy) claims that it stands for *that's a* or *that's the*, but I do not see the resemblance to *atta*.

Comment: Wow, I'd never considered where that came from!

Comment: hm as soon as i read the question i thought "It must be 'That's the'!" That's the boy -> at's the boy - atsdaboy - attaboy

Comment: Note that an allied compressed phrase of encouragement is "attaway!"—meaning "That's the way!"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First of all, Etymonline [agrees](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=attaboy&searchmode=none):

> 1909, from common pronunciation of "that's the boy!" a cheer of encouragement or approval.

Merriam-Webster [throws in](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/attaboy) a "probably" for good measure:

> probably alteration of *that's the boy*
>
> First Known Use: 1909

The most extended discussion I was able to find is in the Dictionary of Slang and Unconventional English by [Eric Partridge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_Partridge):

> **attaboy!** Go it!: US (— 1917); anglicised in 1918. (F. & G.) The *OED* and Collinson
>   derive it from *that's the boy!*, but possibly it represents *at her, boy!*, where
>   *her* is sexless; probably, however, it is a corruption of the exclamatory US *staboy*
>   recorded by Thornton. Dr Douglas Leechman, that eminent anthropologist and notable contributor
>   to the *Dictionary of Canadian English*, wrote to me in 1969: 'Everybody, except the pundits,
>   knows that this is "That's the boy"—"'at's a boy"—"atta boy".'—2. Hence, an approbatory
>   exclam. from ca. 1931, as in D.L. Sayers, *Murder Must Advertise*, 1933, '"Picture of
>   nice girl bending down to put the cushion in the corner of the [railway] carriage. And
>   the headline [of the advertistement]? '*Don't let them pinch your seat*.'" "Attaboy!"
>   said Mr Bredon [Lord Peter Wimsey].'—3. (As *Attaboy*) an Air Transport Auxiliary
>   'plane or member: WW2, then nostalgic. (Jackson.) Suggested by the intitials and punning
>   on senses 1 and 2. See Ancient and Tattered Airmen or Aviators.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, that's a quote from a 2002 reprint of the 1984 (8th) edition. The first edition appeared in 1937, Mr. Partridge was born in 1894 and died in 1979.

Comment: Am I the only one here who frequently hears (and pronounces) this as ‘thattaboy’, with a clearer link to the original form? It’s always been instinctively clear to me that this is where the expression comes from, being quite parallel to “that’s a good boy”, only without the adjective.

Answer (score 7):

It comes from "That's a good boy," through a series of shortenings.

1. That's a good boy.
2. That's a boy. (or, "That's the boy")
3. 'at's a boy.
4. atta boy.

Comment: And you evidence for "good" ever having been part of the expression?

Comment: I guess that's just how it was explained to me.  Let me dig up some evidence.