# What do we call the shift in the orthography of words like "cuppa, fella, attaboy and attagirl"?

Tags: terminology, orthography

I know that words like

> ***cuppa, fella, attaboy*** and ***attagirl***

are contractions of, respectively,

> ***cup of tea, fellow, that's the/a boy*** and ***that's the/a girl***.

I wonder if there is a term which would describe the process through which the orthography of these contracted words changed to what they call ***[phonemic orthography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonemic_orthography)*** (writing words as they are pronounced).

For example, the British ***[cuppa](https://www.google.com/search?q=cuppa%20meaning&safe=strict&sxsrf=ALeKk02J3rFbuU0dzH4ExiJKLi7RD3LygQ%3A1624383989885&ei=9SHSYOG1Na_hkgWHxIboDQ&oq=cupameaning&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAEYADIECAAQDTIGCAAQBxAeMgYIABAHEB4yCAgAEAcQChAeMgYIABAHEB4yBAgAEA0yBggAEAcQHjIGCAAQBxAeMgYIABAHEB4yCAgAEAcQChAeOgcIABBHELADOgcIABCwAxBDUN3VEFjp3RBgjfAQaAJwAngAgAGyAYgBnwSSAQMzLjKYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6yAEKwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz)*** comes from ***cup of tea*** but it renders just ***cup of***.

As for ***attaboy***, it comes from ***[that's the boy](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4251/what-does-the-atta-mean-in-attaboy-and-attagirl/4258#4258)***, but there were stages (*"That's the boy"—"'at's a boy"—"atta boy"* – there is even a variant of *at her, boy!*)

Also, ***cuz*** just popped into my mind ***because*** (!) it became so short. ***Kinda*** seems to be ***kind of*** (!) in between.

So from a proper English orthography there is a shift towards phonemic orthography in informal English. Is there a term for this? Does anyone know of any reliable investigations of this process?

Edit: The question indicated as already existing does shed some light, but the accepted answer is *relaxed pronunciation*. And the question seems to focus on *speech* and *pronunciation*. My question is rather about this tendency to write in this way in informal writing. It may be though that such term does not exist in orthography. The result is phonemic orthography; just wondered if the process leading to it has a name.

Comment: Phonemic orthography applied to novel (and very informal) contractions.

Comment: Yes, I agree it is very informal. The amount of informal writing has increased a lot though.

Comment: @rajah9 we have been through this yesterday. This question has been closed and reopened. But it's ok, the answer to my question may be simply "No, there isn't." :-)

Comment: related: [What is it called when words are deliberately spelled incorrectly but pronunciation is kept unchanged?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46101/) and [Term for using phonetic orthography to make a speaker seem uneducated/vernacular](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/255697/) and [Is there a special word for purposely misspelling a word?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/137922/)

Comment: @Mari-LouA Amazing questions, they are more connected to what I am after, so thanks! In my examples, I feel the intention is to indicate a relaxed attitude, familiarity or even affection, not necessarily that one is illiterate. But that is beside the point of my question.